# Create a screen where user configures tabs

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabbar

Does anyone know of a way to allow the user to select which tabs they would like to have on their iOS Application? (This would be similar to the music app)

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a UITabBarController, this screen appears automatically when you have more than five view controllers set for your tab bar controller's `viewControllers` property. See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) around `-setViewControllers:animated:` and `-moreNavigationController`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Once you have more than 5, where does the edit button go, do I just set the button to do [self setViewControllers:TRUE]; and it pops up?

Comment: Are you talking about the More tab? It appears automatically. You should call `-setViewControllers:animated:` with an *array* of your UIViewControllers that you want the tab bar to manage (and an animated BOOL).

Comment: Ok, but what if you want to have a custom view controller be in place of the more tab, but have an edit button, that calls the setViewControllers and can rearrange the tabs. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible, but probably difficult – the More tab is provided automatically by the controller. Reimplementing similar functionality yourself would be much more work, and I'm not sure all the necessary API is exposed for you to use.